# Give parent div the width of it's floated contents

Tags: html, css

I want to create an outer div that's wide enough to contain all it's children (which are floated left).

This is a basic diagram of what I want to achieve (in pure CSS). I've tried a lot, but can't seem to gasp this concept. The items always start wrapping at the browser viewport.

```
   +--viewport-------------------+
   |                             |
   | +----parent div--------------------------------------------------------^
   | |                           |                                          |
   | | +-------+ +-------+ +--------+ +---------+ +--------+ +-----+        |
   | | |       | |       | |     |  | |         | |        | |     |        |
   | | |       | |       | |     |  | |         | |        | |     |        |
   | | |       | |       | |     |  | |         | |        | |     |        |
   | | +-------+ +-------+ +--------+ +---------+ +--------+ +-----+        |
   | +----------------------------------------------------------------------+
   |                             |
   |                             |
   +-----------------------------+
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Add code. Make it simple for us...

Comment: Set width to parent,
in sliders we do that. floated elements breaks it never make parent to increase width. use css3 calc to set width of parent.
http://jsfiddle.net/aslancods/UTrvg/4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `white-space: nowrap` to the parent div and for the children add `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left`, e.g.:

```css
.parent_div {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.parent_div > div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Here's an example: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UTrvg/)**